# Disable all touch-gestures exept pinch to zoom and jump back to 100% after time x

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I am working on a project where I need to disable all touch-gestures except the pinch to zoom and the zoom should jump back to 100% after e few seconds.

It is a project done in electron.js

I tried to integrate Hammer.js but I don't get it working.

Could anybody please give me a helping hand?
Thanks!

It is mainly a superwide panorama image you can scroll horizontally with a rotary encoder. That works fine!

But now i would like to implement the zooming function without letting move or scroll the image with touch-gestures.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grimm.css">
</head>
<body style="background: white;">
    
    <div id="scroller">
        <div class="scrolling-box">
                
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                <td><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_0.jpg" style="width: 100vh;  height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_1.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_2.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_3.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_4.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_5.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_6.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_7.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_8.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_9.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_10.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_11.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_12.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_13.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_14.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_15.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_16.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_17.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_18.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_19.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_20.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_21.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_22.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_23.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_24.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_25.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_26.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_27.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_28.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_29.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_30.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_31.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_32.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_33.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_34.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_35.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_36.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_37.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_38.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_39.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_40.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_41.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_42.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_43.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_44.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_45.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_46.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_47.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_48.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_49.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_50.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_51.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_52.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_53.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_54.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_55.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_56.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_57.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_58.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_59.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_60.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_61.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_62.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_63.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_64.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_65.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_66.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_67.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_68.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_69.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_70.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_71.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_72.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_73.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_74.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_75.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_76.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_77.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_78.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_79.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_80.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_81.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_82.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_83.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_84.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_85.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><a href="#"><img loading = "lazy"  alt=" " src="images/slice_0_86.jpg"  style="width:  100vh; height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></a></td>
                <td><img loading = "lazy" alt=" " src="images/slice_0_87.jpg" style="width: auto;  height: 100vh; border-width: 0px;"></td>
                </tr>
            
        
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--script type="text/javascript" src="hammer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="touch.js"></script-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/touch-action/

Comment: @MrT I tried the way through css and i can manage the touch-gestures but i would like to make the zoom flip back to original size (like Instagram zoom).

Comment: @Spectric Shure. What part you want me to show? The HTML?

Comment: @PietroManzella HTML would be good. Thanks